# What should be the minimum quantity of food that can be offered to God?

Tags: gods, belief, food

What is the minimum quantity of food, **recommended scripturally**, that can be offered to God? Does the quantity varies : Both in normal daily pújã and the occasional big pújã?

Does the kind and quantity of food also varies as per the nature and attributes of the deity too?

How about, any difference between offering food (bhoga - भोग) at one's own home and that at a temple?

Should offerings be **always** proportional to one's own financial capacity or status?

Should one offer the same amount of food that one eats?

What are the general acceptable beliefs on this whole concept of offering (भोग / नैवेद्य), as per scriptures?

Comment: How is it opinion based question

Comment: @Vivikta thanks bro for the nice edit(s).

Comment: Agama Shastras deal with how much food must be offered depending on size of Vigraha (1 padi for 1 foot etc.)